# how to make nginx redirect

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting, webserver

I'm trying to do the following:
There is a site where you can find a user in the format `http://localhost/username` . I tried to make a rule that if there is no file on the server, then it will redirect to `index.php?username=username`. But the problem is that it redirects everything, even js and css. I want to do it like this, if the file was on the server, then it would access it, and if not, then it would make a request

```
index.php?username=username
```

There is this piece of code:

```
rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?type=userinfo&username=$1 last;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`try_files`](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) to determine if the file already exists, and branch to a [named location](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) containing your rewrite rule, if it does not.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.+)$ /index.php?type=userinfo&username=$1 last;
}
```